# Will all algorithms in h2o wil support in h2o automl like naive bayes, time series

Tags: h2o

The all algorithms that are available in h2o will applicable in Automl. For example, will H2O automl run on these algorithms like time series, Cox Proportional Hazards (CoxPH), naive bayes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#optional-miscellaneous-parameters), during H2O's AutoML

> all appropriate H2O algorithms will be used if the search stopping criteria allows and if the `include_algos` option is not specified

If you would like to specify certain algos, you can specify a list or vector in the `include_algos` argument (see [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/include_algos.html)).